# Problema com o VS Code , package java

Tags: java, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, packages, path

Galera estou com problema há 3 dias no VS Code já tirei, coloquei de novo, apaguei a pasta ".vscode" e mesmo assim persiste, se eu criar um projeto novo no `vs code` ele funciona normalmente se eu fecho e abro ele de novo já não funciona mais, estava usando `vs code` há 1 semana e estava normal e do nada esse erro.

> The declared package "apricativo" does not match the expected package
> ""Java(536871240)

e se eu tiro da pasta e deixo ele no SRC ele pede para criar um arquivo source path.

```
{
    "java.project.sourcePaths": [
        "src/apricativo",
        "src"
    ]
}
```

então se eu crio uma pasta e coloco o arquivo ali ele funciona mas sem o package apricativo; no codigo
eu não sei se é alguma configuração que eu mexi sem querer um bug do vs code? isso começou quando eu perdi meus arquivos e tive que criar uma pasta nova e então dei pull no git bash e então parece que o que faço é só quebrar o galho, além de ser um incomodo que fica várias pastas no git hub.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

a imagem mostra um teste agora mesmo.
o lado direito é um projeto acabei de criar e o lado esquerdo é o mesmo projeto, na pasta onde normalmente eu pesquiso os projeto.

Então se eu fecho o projeto acabei de criar e abro ele normalmente,não funciona

Eu não sei se deveria configurar alguma coisa que não sei, eu só abri o vs code instalei o pack que eles recomenda (java) e baixei meu repositório no Git Hub.
e então nenhum dos códigos de lá funciona.
nem se eu abrir individualmente.

Answer (score -1):

Olá, a JVM esta dizendo que o pacote não foi encontrado, notei no seu código que não esta declarado a referencia do pacote no main, por exemplo se o método main está em uma classe dentro do pacote aplicativo

package aplicativo;

public class App {

public static voi main(String[] args) throws Exception {
System.out.println("Hello, World");

}
}

espero ter ajudado.